# Is there any way to create NuxtJS App using existing Docker Image and without using npm create-app command

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, nuxt.js, docker-container

I am new to NuxtJS and Docker. Created one Docker container for NuxtJS application and its running successfully and I pushed the image to docker hub as well. Now, I need to create one NuxtJS application with the existing docker image and not using `npm init nuxt-app newApp`. Is there any way to achieve this? Any lead would be most appreciated.

My Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM <existing_image_name>

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir /dockerapp
WORKDIR /dockerapp

# Add current directory code to working directory
ADD . /dockerapp/

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=4000
```

docker-compose file is

```
version: "3"

services:
  docker-app:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      - NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NUXT_PORT=4000
    volumes:
      - .:/dockerapp/
```

When doing `docker-compose up -d --build`, getting the below error in docker container

```
Attaching to docker-app_dockerapp_1

dockerapp_1  | 

dockerapp_1  | > demo_dev@1.0.0 dev /dockerapp

dockerapp_1  | > nuxt

dockerapp_1  | 

dockerapp_1  | sh: nuxt: not found

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! file sh

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! errno ENOENT

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! syscall spawn

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! demo_dev@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! 

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the demo_dev@1.0.0 dev script.

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

dockerapp_1  | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

dockerapp_1  | 

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

dockerapp_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-23T03_12_56_634Z-debug.log

docker-app_dockerapp_1 exited with code 1
```

My project folder structure is,

[image]